# C# how to create while loop to validate if object is null

Tags: c#, validation

I am having issues with two validations working together, one in the Main method and the other one in the Controller Class.

So this is my static method inside the Main. Basically I ask the user to input the ID for an "Employee", the ID is a property of a Class named Employee, and then I show a message saying if that employee exists or not. Let's assume that I have several Employee objects already created. I know it's a form of while loop but I just cant get it right.

My method inside the controller class is correct so there is no need to change anything. Basically it takes the ID and returns null if the Employee object does not exist or returns the object if it does exist. I need to take that null if the employee doesnt exist and create a loop that keeps asking the user to input a correct ID until he does, then the loop ends. Thank you, sorry if I did not explain it correctly.

```
    public static void mymethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter your Employee ID: ");
        int ID = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("----------------------------");
        Employee employee = controllerclass.findemployee(ID);
        int i = 0;
        bool flag = false;
        while (!flag)
        {
            if (!flag)
            {
                if (ID != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("The employee exists");
                    flag = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valid ID");
                }
            }
            i++;
        }
```

My method inside the controller class is correct so there is no need to change anything. Basically it takes the ID and returns null if the Employee object does not exist or returns the object if it does exist. I need to take that null if the employee doesnt exist and create a loop that keeps asking the user to input a correct ID until he does, then the loop ends. Thank you, sorry if I did not explain it correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a do-while loop, something like this:

```
boolean flag = false;
do {
    if(flag)
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valid ID");
    else 
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter your Employee ID: ");
    try{
         int ID = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    } catch (FormatException e){
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter an integer");
        flag = false;
        continue;
    } 
    employee = controllerclass.findemployee(ID);
    flag = true;
} while (employee == null) //employee will be null if not found
Console.WriteLine("The employee exists");
```

The do while makes sure it happens at least once. The flag conditional will happen after the first entry; if they get it right the first time it'll never happen.

Comment: ID is int so it will never be null.

Comment: Good point. I was just basing it on the questioner's code. I'll edit the answer to reflect that.

Comment: Thank you so much @jimboweb , I took your code and changed some things and now it works exactly as I wanted. Thanks for taking the time to help a noobie.

Answer (score 2):

One detail is that an `int` can never be null because it's a value type. You could change it to `int?` which is a *nullable* `int` - it can have a value or be null.

The key to making a `while' loop work is that whatever condition it's checking has to be changed *inside* the loop.

In this case `ID` is getting set before the loop starts, and there's nothing inside the loop to ever change it.

You could do something like this. (This is a little more nesting than I usually do, but it works.)

```
public static void mymethod()
{
    Employee employee = null
    while(employee == null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter your Employee ID: ");
        int ID = 0;
        var input = Console.ReadLine();
        if(int.TryParse(input, out ID))
        {
            employee = controllerclass.findemployee(ID);
            if(employee == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The employee does not exist");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The employee exists");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valid ID.");
        }
    } // Doesn't exit the loop until we have an employee
```

The loop will execute as long as `employee` is null. So until they enter something that returns a valid employee, it will keep going.

I used `int.TryParse` to check the value they entered. It returns `true` if what they entered is an integer, otherwise `false`. That way if they entered a valid integer we check for the employee. If it's not even a valid integer then it lets them know.

One way to think of a `while` loop is just to think of what condition you're trying to meet before you exit the loop. In this case you want `employee` to be something other than null. So the loop can begin with `while(employee==null)`.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you want to do something at least once and possibly more times until a condition has been met (id is found), you should use the `do while` construct. Here is some code:

```
int id;
bool idIsNotNumeric = true;
do
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter your Employee ID: ");
    string idEntered = Console.ReadLine();
    idIsNotNumeric = !int.TryParse(idEntered, out id);

    // other stuff you want to keep doing

} while (idIsNotNumeric || controllerclass.findemployee(id) == null);

Console.WriteLine("The employee exists");
```